# JSONP not display in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsonp

I'm new in Angular and I have problem with display data. I dont know what is the problem, because all data from API and form controller in console.log show correct.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.jsonp("http://localhost/a.json")
  .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
   console.log(status);
     console.log(data);
     console.log(headers);
     console.log(config);console.log("success");
   $scope.picture = data;
  })
  .error(function(error, status, headers, config) {
     console.log(status);
     console.log(error);
     console.log(headers);
     console.log(config);
     console.log("Error occured");
  });
  
});
```

The JSONP works, but my code is not displaying in the HTML.

Why its not displaying the data?

my HTML :

```html
<html>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in picture">
    {{ x }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is json format ?

Comment: show html where you are trying to display data

Comment: just display {{picture}} in html and tell anything is display or not.

Comment: Copy and paste the output of this line console.log(data);

Comment: @PareshGami it still doesn't display

Comment: ok. in response of data what you get?

Comment: @PareshGami its blank, whether because I use jsonp?

Comment: @PareshGami yes, but problematic in Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: Please try to add this code in server's index file http://pastebin.com/vNS60gWw

Comment: @PareshGami but i not have permission to the server. Can it just change from the client? or it must edit on server?

Comment: a.json file is live on server? can you send me url if you dont mind